# How to static_assert in member templates only when they are actually used?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, member, static-assert

Consider this simple class:

```
template<class T>
class Foo{
public:
  Foo(T const& val)
    : _val(val) {}

  template<class U>
  Foo(Foo<U> const&){
    static_assert(false,"Cannot convert from Foo<U> to Foo<T>.");
  }

  operator T&() { return _val; }
  operator T const&() const{ return _val; }

private:
  T _val;
};
```

It allows implicit construction from the template type and implicit conversion back to that type, a simple wrapper.

Now, I do not want to enable conversion between unrelated `Foo`s, which would be possible because of these implicit constructions / conversions. I could make the templated copy-ctor private, but I wan't to emit a helpful diagnostic through `static_assert`.

The problem, as shown [here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/t21Dk) is that the `static_assert` failes even when I not even try to copy the type! In Visual Studio, I get the behaviour I want, though I think that is due to the way VS parses templates. Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: I'm pretty sure gcc isn't acting correctly here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It fails compilation, because compiler can clearly see`static_assert` would  fail no matter what. It doesn't depend on`U` and `T` in any way.

I think you wanted something like this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<T,U>::value,"Cannot convert from Foo<U> to Foo<T>.");
```

Comment: Nopes, second version won't work because of the implicit conversion available: http://ideone.com/iNaP2

Comment: @Xeo: Hmmm. `std::is_same<T,U>` is the solution to your problem. Use it.

Comment: @Nawaz: The real code isn't that trivial, but the delayed parsing through the dependent name does indeed solve the problem. `template<class> fake : std::false_type{};` and I was done. Thought of that after reformulating the question in my head to include "delayed parsing". :|

Comment: @Xeo: By the way, note that `Foo(const Foo&)` is not working because of implicit conversions which your class provides, not because of standard implicit conversion. http://ideone.com/2bWHi

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, I know that. I even mentioned that in the question. :P

Answer (score 2):

It seems std::is_convertible is the solution.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible :

"If an imaginary rvalue of type From can used in the return statement of a function returning To, that is, if it can be converted to To using implicit conversion, provides the member constant value equal to true. Otherwise value is false. "